# Update data from MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I differentiate 4 different situation when I update data in MySQL using PDO. Those situations are:

1. Data have been updated and change
2. Database execution failed
3. Same data already exist and are unaffected by update
4. Key for updating data was not found

I've been using `$stmt->execute()` to check any of those situation, but it would always return `true` even when situation number 1, 3 and 4 happen.

Then I try to use `$stmt->rowCount()` to count number of affected rows, but it also went wrong when I wanted to tell the user that either the data have been updated or the user tried to input data that already exist in the database or that the key was not found.

Comment: For #2, you should just enable exceptions with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: What is the difference between 1 and 3? An `UPDATE` implies that the data does already exist. For 3, do you mean that the new data attempted by the update is the same as the old?